# How to get a dynamic URL from a site?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x

I have as an ambition to create a program that will sort data from my school website planning. For this I would like to get the planning from the week as a json file to be able to parse it but I don't know how to get started with my url because it's a dynamic one.

Example `https://my_site.com/planning/#!/?start=2019-12-02&end=2019-12-08`
but the week after it's `https://my_site.com/planning/#!/?start=2019-12-09&end=2019-12-15` so I don't know how to automate my function to get the new url each week/days/months.

Comment: You can create any required date using `datetime` package in python, similar can also be done for js.

Comment: @JayVasant Ok but how can I automate my function to go get the link from the website knowing it's dynamic ?

Comment: what is the `#!` for?

Comment: @Skarlett I don't know, the url is generated like that, I just changed the `my_site.com`

Comment: As he said above, you can create the date parts with `datetime` in any format you need in python. The rest is just some very simple string concatenation, no? Adding said date parts to the rest of the URL?

Comment: @Skarlett it's called a hashbang and you should use the search to find out more.